# How can I give rep to a wiki answer?

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion

Lets say a user created an answer to a question and because he is nice enough and he knows people can concentrate on his answer as a base and add more information to it he marked the answer as community wiki.

But the answer is good enough already, he is the sole contributor to it and shown good effort to putting the answer up and maintaining it.

I want to give extra rep to the guy.

If I assign a bounty to the question with reason "One of the answer is good and deserves extra bounty" with the intention of giving that user the bounty will he get it? How is that sorted out? What if he is not the main contributor but the changes made by him are so important that he still deserves that bounty?

Comment: This should be helpful: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2342

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [MSO FAQ on bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> Bounties are not affected by community wiki mode. When you award a bounty to an answer marked community wiki, the reputation bonus will be awarded to the user who posted the original revision of the answer.

So just apply the bounty to the answer. The person will get the reputation.

Comment: Thanks, clear. Just for the 2nd part of the question, if another user makes a huge contribution to a community wiki answer there is no (normal) way to giving that user a bounty, it will be assigned to the original poster right?

Comment: Yeah there's no split. However much it has been edited, the original poster gets the whole bounty.