# Giving Credit for an Edit

Tags: discussion, editing, reputation

Someone did a really nice job enhancing one of my answers and I have a simple question.  Is there any way I can transfer rep as a thank you? Do I have any other options to give him credit?  I,m not sure what the protocol is.

Comment: upvote one of their Q or A that seems good

Comment: Sure, if thats the only way then thats what I will do

Comment: Just be careful not to go too far overboard so you don't get automatically detected as a serial upvoter. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We are all here to help each-other, so I would say pass on that helpfulness to others.

Also, A lot of older questions for some users may be less than perfect, or have gone unnoticed, So finding a couple of things to edit on some of their older questions would not only be of great help to the user but to the whole site.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, As aking1012 said in a comment, You may want to give some upvotes on their question or answers, if you think they deserve so. But, doing serial upvoting is caught by the system as unexpected behavior.

I also read a comment by an user who said, "I'll try to give you bounty, as soon as possible". I don't know the exact procedure, but what I understand is, He will declare a bounty where an answer existed there already and then apply bounty. In this way, A user can give extra rep to a good answer.

Check this question for extra

[How can I give rep to a wiki answer?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2310/how-can-i-give-rep-to-a-wiki-answer)

Comment: +1  These responses have been very helpful and I have noted some of the pitfalls in irregular voting etc.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest help you could give someone on a stack-exchange site is of course to answer a question they have.

If they've a question open, and you yourself don't know the answer, you could open a bounty on that question, which will give the question more attention, and hence up the chances that they get an answer.